# How to Structure Database and create API for the same database, in case if single users is a member of multiple country

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, join

I have created one application, in which user have access to application as per specification of the country & single user can be a member of multiple country.
So I have created two table, one for user's details & another to store country table.

Table Design that i have tried:-
1<sup>st</sup> table `(Users table):- UserID (Primary Key), Name, EmailId, UserRole` 
2<sup>nd</sup> table `(Country table) :- UserId (foreign key),CountryId (primary key), Country_name`

I have created `ASP.NET MVC` `GET` & `POST` api & in Single `Get Request (api/GetUser(id))`, I want whole data of that User which can be obtain
by using join query between these two tables.

Code:-

```
public IQueryable<tblUserRecord> GettblUserRecords()
{
           var query = (from g in db.tblUserRecords
                         join u in db.tblCountryNames on g.UserId equals u.UserId
                         select new { g, u, });
            return query;
}
```

Problem/Error I am Facing:-

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable<>' to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

To Solve above issue I have tried changing return type of function to `List<tblUserRecord>`, also changed `return query` to `return query.toList()`. But Nothing works

---

**Note**:- While creating entity model I have selected both tables.

Comment: Why are you storing the names of countries repeatedly? There are only ~200 countries currently - surely a lookup of some kind is indicated?

Comment: then what will be best way?...  & How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return the data in both the `tblUserRecord` model and `tblCountryName` model, then you could create a wrapper model to hold this data and have your method return that. This could look like:

```
public class UserAndCountry 
{
    public tblUserRecord UserRecord {get; set;}
    public tblCountryName CountryRecord {get; set;}
}
```

then your method querying your data would look like:

```
public IQueryable<UserAndCountry> GettblUserRecords()
{
   var query = (from g in db.tblUserRecords
                 join u in db.tblCountryNames on g.UserId equals u.UserId
                 select new UserAndCountry { UserRecord = g, CountryRecord = u });
   return query;
}
```

To elaborate on the error you're receiving, this is not happening because of returning an `IQueryable` vs `List` as you mentioned. It's happening because you're selecting an anonymous object to build the `IQueryable` out of but your method defines the return type as `IQueryable<tblUserRecord>`.

Also note that by convention, class names are normally upper camel cased in .NET